# Password fails to login

Tags: password

First of all i have ubuntu 14.04 lts.
I have deactivated the login need of a password since the 1st day.minutes ago i upgraded the ati graphics from the official software update. I restarted the pc and for the first time,system aaks for a password to login.i m typing the password but the screen flashes and asks the password again.no invalid password message appeared.any suggestions?
I used the ctrl alt F1 and F2 it s working,logged in but i dnt know what to do at the terminal

Comment: Yeap.i just saw.thank you.i ll go with the reinstall as well.

Comment: Nothing works,so reinstallation is done already